# Convert BSD-3 license project with own modification added to Elastic license

Tags: licensing, bsd

What should be considered to make an original project released under BSD-3 license, added modifications (many things changed) to [Elastic License 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/licensing/elastic-license), at least for the changed parts?

I assume I will keep the BSD-3 note/license and add paragraph that changed parts are under Elastic License 2.0?

1. What should be also considered? Could be problematic/blocker?
2. Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide details, which parts of the language of the BSD license is unclear to you.
The Elastic License is not free, therefore the parts of your question related to it will likely not be answered here.

Comment: You may also wish to read [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/4149/2870) on Law.SE specifically addressing the question of releasing a work derived from BSD-licensed content under a less-permissive licence.